# Vim NERDTree highlight line color

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

I've found how I can change the color of the folders and such, but how do I change it when the cursor highlights over it?

I don't like how highlighted folders turn white. I want it to stay gray, because it's too confusing having it turn the same color as files.

[image]

Comment: you might want to try this plugin `github.com/tiagofumo/vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight`. It probably not only solve your problem but also makes your NERDTree look a whole lot nicer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For terminal vim

```
:highlight CursorLine ctermfg=grey
```

For macvim

```
:highlight CursorLine guifg=grey
```

> See :help highlight for more options.